# Regular Expression for pattern surrounded by optional angle brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find a number optionally surrounded by angle brackets, i.e. `<>`. The pattern I'm using,

```
<?(?P<fraction>[-+]?[-+0-9.Ee]+)>?
```

can find the surrounding brackets. But if there is only one of the brackets then it also matches. I only want it to match if both the open and close angle brackets are there or if neither of them are there.

I want to match things such as:

```
-11.88
<0.012541>
-<3.14>
<-2.98>
```

And I don't want to match:

```
<1.23
<-abcdefg>
```

I also don't want to have to repeat the pattern I use to match the number. That feels like an error-prone solution.

Comment: But you want to include those brackets in the match? Or only the number?

Comment: I don't need to keep the brackets, but they optionally need to be matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps used named conditionals if you don't want to repeat the number part of the regex:

```
^[-+]?(?P<o><)?[-+0-9.Ee]+(?(o)>|)$
```

Breakdown:

```
^               # Start
  [-+]?         # Get a -/+ if any
  (?P<o><)?     # Get a < if any
  [-+0-9.Ee]+   # Get the numbers
  (?(o)>|)      # If a < was matched, match a >, otherwise, don't match anything
$               # End
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uV2zV0)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/TEQoeq)

---

If you want something to really validate the number (and prevent stuff like `-<-2>`), you can use something like this:

```
^(?P<s>[-+])?(?P<o><)?(?(s)|[-+]?)\d+(?:\.\d+(?:[Ee][-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?(?(o)>|)$
```

Note: I usually don't validate things like `.2e-.3` (i.e. decimals without leading zero) so the above prevents that also. It does work if the string is `0.2e-0.3` though but allows for both leading and trailing zeros.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX6xB2)

Comment: This is exactly what I want---and it keeps getting better the more you edit. I wish I could give you +2 for reading my mind!

Comment: @Jeremy I was initially going with `\d+\.\d+` for the number and you didn't seem to put much importance as to the signs, so I just simplified it throughout the edits ^^; The most foolproof solution would be something making sure the number is not just a bunch of `---` or `eeEee`.

Comment: this fails for the following input `-<-3.0123>`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Whatever you say. If you see my first regex (in the edit history), you'd see that I checked for that at the start and removed it later after noticing that OP's regex for the digits was `[-+0-9.Ee]+`. This means that there's not only numbers being validated, and more than that,`eeeeee` will also pass the test. Plus, why would a double minus make it wrong? `-(-2)` is equivalent to `2`.

Answer (score 2):

**Naive solution:** copy/paste the pattern (first alternative with angle brackets, second alternative without):

```
<(?P<fraction>[-+]?[-+0-9.Ee]+)>|(?P<fraction>[-+]?[-+0-9.Ee]+)
```

---

**More advanced solution:** Take a look at [If-Then-Else Conditionals in Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). They allow you to specify a pattern to match if a certain group (named or numbered) matched. So, in your case you could see if there was a match for a left-angle bracket and only then match a right-angle bracket.

Comment: I don't think python's builtin `re` module supports "if-then-else" conditionals.  the newer `regex` module (which will eventually replace `re`) may support it though ...

Comment: @mgilson: strangely the new regex module doesn't seem to have this feature.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to copy/past the pattern. Should have been more explicit in my original question. It has now been updated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple and straight forward with no special features required:

[`^(-?<\d+\.\d+>)|(<-?\d+\.\d+>)|(-?\d+\.\d+)$`](http://regex101.com/r/gF2eR7)

*simple and easy to maintain is the key to regular expressions, they are best used for matching and are not doing procedural conditional logic inside them, which is what you are trying to do*